# operator() overloading for structure

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I'm trying to use a structure for my map in c++. The structure is simple:

```
struct index{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
  bool operator<(const index &b){
    bool out = true;
    if ( x == b.x ){
      if ( y == b.y ){
        out = z < b.z;
      } else out = y < b.y;
    } else out = x < b.x;
    return out;
  }
};
```

But when I compile I get an error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h: In member function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const
>   _Tp&) const [with _Tp = membrane::index]':
>       /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:347:
>   instantiated from '_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = membrane::index, _Tp = std::set, std::less >,
>   std::allocator > >, _Compare =
>   std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator,
>   std::less >, std::allocator >
>
> > > > ]'
> > > >             memMC.cpp:551:   instantiated from here

Which, as far as I can tell, means that I need to overload the () operator. However I don't know what this operator usually do so I don't know how to overwrite it correctly. Wikipedia tells me that this is a cast operator but I don't think they return bool...

The compiler crush at the first time I try to access a map element using [] operator.

Comment: Where are you getting the compile error?

Comment: That error doesn't mean that you need to overload `operator()`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore At the first time I use the [] operator with the index

Comment: More context. You gave the line that was generating the error but not the error message itself. But I am guessing it is because you have no declared the comparison const.

Comment: @LokiAstari What is a comparison const? Google doesn't give a naive result when I search this...

Comment: @Yotam - it means that, inside `std::less::operator()`, which was instantiated inside `std::map::operator[]`, there was an error. You didn't post the part of the error messages that tells us what went wrong in `std::less::operator()`.

Comment: @Yotam - Loki meant "Your comparison member function (i.e. `operator<`) must be declared as a const member function." See, for example, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ke686zh(v=vs.80).aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: @Rob, Thanks. I'm waiting till I'll be able to mark Loki's answer as correct.

Comment: Hmm, the compiler output is "In member function ... instantiated from ... instantiated from here", so it doesn't even mention the error. There seems to be something missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try making the comaprison const:

```
struct index{
  int x;
  int y;
 int z;
  bool operator<(const index &b) const
                               //^^^^^ Missing this,
```

Comment: @Rob: Less. It was 12 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Try a free overload:

```
bool operator < (const index &a, const index &b)
{
    if (a.x == b.x)
    {
        if (a.y == b.y)
        {
            return a.z < b.z;
        }
        else
        {
            return a.y < b.y;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will also work. But the answer to the question is that he was missing constness on the lhs (as the member operator< was not const)(which you have added it explicitly in this free function version).

Comment: Usually a free function is preferred because it allows conversions in the first argument and is therefore symmetric in its arguments.